# Issues with Bluetooth Mouse in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, 20.04

I've got a Logitech V270 bluetooth mouse that has worked fine in the past with previous versions of Ubuntu (and other flavours of Linux, and [even] Windows). However, when I've paired it with my HP Elitebook 850 G6 running Ubuntu 20.04, the mouse stops moving the cursor when I leave it for a few seconds. Sometimes a click will wake the mouse, other times it needs a scroll on the wheel, but if I can wake it it works perfectly ... until I again leave it to type for a few seconds.

To be fair, I've never used the mouse with this computer before, so I have no idea if it would happen under Windows, but it worked perfectly with my other HP Elitebook 850 G3 running Ubuntu 16.04.

If anyone has any ideas where I could start looking at, I'd be much appreciative :)

Comment: Have you checked the mouse battery?  When my BT mouse goes flakey, it's always the battery in my case.

Comment: Yup, tried with fresh batteries, same thing happened :(

Comment: This is the same issue I was about to post. In this case a Logi MX Master 2S and a Logi MX 705. Not only that but when moving the mouse there is some evident lag (either that or I am having some serious mental issues).

Comment: I'm have the same issue after upgrade. Ubuntu becomes very unstable...

Answer (score 5):

And if this doesn't work do the following:

Type:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Completely replace line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

With:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash btusb.enable_autosuspend=n usbcore.autosuspend=-1 usbcore.autosuspend_delay_ms=-1"
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for saving.

Then type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution similar to [that of mathias](https://askubuntu.com/a/1249222/22949) worked for me:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add `"btusb.enable_autosuspend=0"` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score -1):

Modifying my `/etc/bluetooth/input.conf` solved the problem.

Type

```
sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/input.conf
```

and modify the `IdleTimeout` value (in minutes) - for me 30 minutes is fine but you can set it to 0 to deactivate turning off Bluetooth.

[image: screenshot of the file content]

Comment: IdleTimeout value is set to 0 by default. Hence, this is not the right way to do it.