# Bluetooth mouse sporadically disconnects

Tags: drivers, usb, mouse, bluetooth

Ubuntu 20.04, Microsoft Bluetooth Mouse 3600 sporadically disconnects after random periods of time.
dmesg:

```
[   62.599719] input: BluetoothMouse3600 Mouse as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:045E:0916.0006/input/input22
[   62.600185] input: BluetoothMouse3600 Consumer Control as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:045E:0916.0006/input/input23
[   62.600623] hid-generic 0005:045E:0916.0006: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v1.00 Mouse [BluetoothMouse3600] on a0:a8:cd:68:72:5b
[ 1154.754010] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 1593.455401] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 1593.455668] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI reset during shutdown failed
[ 1593.640323] usb 1-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 1596.243791] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 1596.354810] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07dc, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 1596.354818] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 1596.370354] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370710018002030d00
[ 1596.371284] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
[ 1596.579714] usb 1-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 1596.585409] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[ 1596.601602] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[ 1596.692305] usb 1-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=0489, idProduct=e00f, bcdDevice= 5.96
[ 1596.692309] usb 1-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1596.692311] usb 1-1.6: Product: Broadcom Bluetooth Device
[ 1596.692314] usb 1-1.6: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
[ 1596.692316] usb 1-1.6: SerialNumber: EC55F9CFAE09
[ 1596.706683] Bluetooth: hci1: urb 00000000c2fe7b7a failed to resubmit (2)
[ 1597.562595] input: BluetoothMouse3600 Mouse as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:045E:0916.0007/input/input24
[ 1597.563299] input: BluetoothMouse3600 Consumer Control as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:045E:0916.0007/input/input25
[ 1597.563954] hid-generic 0005:045E:0916.0007: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v1.00 Mouse [BluetoothMouse3600] on a0:a8:cd:68:72:5b
[ 1598.727679] Bluetooth: hci1: command 0x1005 tx timeout
[ 1600.743738] Bluetooth: hci1: command 0x0c23 tx timeout
[ 1602.759705] Bluetooth: hci1: command 0x0c14 tx timeout
[ 1604.775611] Bluetooth: hci1: command 0x0c25 tx timeout
[ 1606.791653] Bluetooth: hci1: command 0x0c38 tx timeout
[ 1630.742475] input: BluetoothMouse3600 Mouse as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:045E:0916.0008/input/input26
[ 1630.742973] input: BluetoothMouse3600 Consumer Control as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:045E:0916.0008/input/input27
[ 1630.743506] hid-generic 0005:045E:0916.0008: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v1.00 Mouse [BluetoothMouse3600] on a0:a8:cd:68:72:5b
[ 1635.775199] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
```

As we can see it resets USB device #7 (lsusb -v -t):

```
...
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
        |__ Port 2: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
            ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
        |__ Port 2: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
            ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
...
```

This device is integrated Bluetooth 4.1 controller provided along with Intel 7260 AC card. Btw card itself doesn't reset.

linux-firmware version:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-firmware
ii  linux-firmware                                              1.187                                      all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
```

kernel version:

```
uname -a
Linux xxx 5.4.0-33-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:53:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

UPD1: found a similar issue here - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1796553

Testing proposed solution - add "btusb.enable_autosuspend=0" into kernel params

UPD2: btusb.enable_autosuspend=0 - didn't work
Similar issue - [Issues with Bluetooth Mouse in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235456/issues-with-bluetooth-mouse-in-ubuntu-20-04)
Testing proposed solutions - add "btusb.enable_autosuspend=n usbcore.autosuspend=-1 usbcore.autosuspend_delay_ms=-1" into kernel params