# Lenovo BT mouse doesn't work with Lenovo Laptop

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, lenovo

I've recently moved one of my laptops to Ubuntu 22.04.01. I've been working through some issues, but one that I have failed to find a solution for is my Bluetooth mouse doesn't work...mostly.
It detects fine, connects fine and even works for a split second on boot... then never works again. Works in windows fine (dual boot), so it's not the mouse.
Plug in the dongle and it's fine. Dongles are terrible. No one should have to use that garbage in 2023.
Browsing around and I find some Grub related fixes (didn't work) and a bluetooth/input.conf that sets the timeout value. But that doesn't work either.
This article seems to touch on both of those fixes that don't work.
[Issues with Bluetooth Mouse in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235456/issues-with-bluetooth-mouse-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help, can you please add some additional context to your question such as: the model/version of the mouse you're using (this could be helpful if this particular model is known to cause problems). As well, it would be useful to provide the output of any warnings/errors generated. To do this enter the following command: `sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`. Please add to the question. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response, Ubuntu Bluetooth settings shows The mouse is a Lenovo Legion M600. The laptop is a Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5.

EDIT: submitted too early on accident.
dmesg doesn't show any errors, this appears to be the entry for the mouse:
hid-generic 0005:17EF:60E7.0007: input,hidraw5: BLUETOOTH HID v1.00 Mouse [Legion M600 Mouse] on dc:e9:94:0c:46:f8